# Swing JCombobox component doesn't return right value

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing JComboBox filled with a list of objects of type Person, where Person is as follows:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String login;
    private String personFirstName;
    private String personLastName;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return personFirstName;
    }

    public void setPersonFirstName(String personFirstName) {
        this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    }

    public String getPersonLastName() {
        return personLastName;
    }

    public void setPersonLastName(String personLastName) {
        this.personLastName = personLastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Person) {
            Person person = (Person) obj;

            if (this.getPersonFirstName() == null) {
                if (person.getPersonFirstName() != null)
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!this.getPersonFirstName().equals(person.getPersonFirstName()))
                    return false;
            }
            if (this.getPersonLastName() == null) {
                if (person.getPersonLastName() != null)
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!this.getPersonLastName().equals(person.getPersonLastName()))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;

        } else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {

        if (this.getLogin() != null) {
            return this.getLogin().compareTo(p.getLogin());
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    // the login is unique for every user.
    public int hashCode() {
        if (this.getLogin() != null) {
            return this.getLogin().hashCode() ^ 3;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The problem is, i have on my combobox 3 users with respectively **login - firstName lastName** as follows:

**lawrence - lawrence stevens**

**lawrencev - lawrence victor**

**lawrencec - lawrence miller**

When i select any of these users

```
  userCombobox.getSelectedItem()
```

always returns **lawrence - lawrence stevens**

Comment: Include the code that builds your JComboBox in your question.

Comment: Yes, a [mcve] would be worth a million bucks

Comment: I would guess your equal() or hashcode() method is not implemented correctly. Test your implementation and forget about the GUI. So create your 3 objects and assign then to variables person1, person2, person3. Then you can add basic debug code like: `System.out.println( person1.equals(person2));` Once this works then you should be able to use your objects in a combo box.

Comment: Your `hashCode` method uses different variables than `equals` method. That might not be an issue but should not be used

Comment: No MCVE, no improvement in the question, why?

Answer (score 0):

The Person class seems to work. The problem is probably in your other code. If you are using Eclipse, then consider using the built-in generators for hashCode() and equals(). Eclipse also generates a good toString() for debugging. My short test that works fine (selected item is printed on change):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lawrence");
    Person[] persons = new Person[] { //
            new Person("lawrence", "lawrence", "stevens"), //
            new Person("lawrencev", "lawrence", "victor"), //
            new Person("lawrencec", "lawrence", "miller") };
    JComboBox<Person> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(persons);
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(">" + comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
    frame.add(comboBox);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Added this constructor in Person:

```
public Person(String login, String personFirstName, String personLastName) {
    super();
    this.login = login;
    this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    this.personLastName = personLastName;
}
```